# objects lives on heap .it consist of instance variable .does it contains method also and when we call a method from object how it goes to stack?

Tags: java

An object lives on the heap. It consists of instance variables. Does it contain methods too, and when we call a method from the object how does it go to the stack?

if I create an object

```
Test obj=new Test();
obj.start();
```

Where is the method code ? Is it in object in heap memory or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

The method code is not in the heap - it is in a static area of memory that is populated when the class data is loaded.  An object instance contains a reference to this static memory area that allows the runtime system to look up the appropriate method when it is called - this is how method overriding works.  Let's say you're calling an instance's `equals` method - at runtime the JVM looks into the class's static memory area, and either finds the address of an overridden `equals` method or else it follows a link to the superclass's static memory area in order to find its `equals` method, stopping when the JVM finds an overridden `equals` method or else when the JVM finds the `Object` memory area with its default `equals` method.

Answer (score 1):

The method code is not duplicated for every instance. Each method is stored only once.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-jvm-memory-types/:

> (...) **method area is part of non-heap memory**. It stores per-class  structures, code for methods and constructors. Per-class structure means runtime constants and static fields.

See also: [Where methods live? Stack or in Heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208695/where-methods-live-stack-or-in-heap)